# Common differentiable approximation of $f(x) = |x|$ and $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, approximation

Is there a common approximation (like commonly used in applications) of the functions

$$
f(x) = |x|
$$

and it's two variable version

$$
f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}
$$

I'm trying to come up with a potential function of similar expression, but I have the issue that these two aren't differentiable in $0$.

Comment: How is it not instead... They're both norms but on different domains...Actually the first one is a restriction of the second one... Just set y=0.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Is there any reason you are not satisfied with an approximation $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2+a^2}$ for a finite but small $a$?

Comment: Didn't think of that... Can I extrapolate a uniform convergent sequence?

Comment: I doubt that... If you want uniform convergence, you would need something more elaborate I think

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Nothing so far. I doubt you could get uniform convergence to a derivative that doesn't exist. Really, your application might not require it, maybe if you add more details on what you need this for?

Comment: I honestly don't remember the application I was looking for... Sometimes I ask questions and I get feedback after ages. I have a feeling I can build a sequence and apply the DCT, which would be good enough.